# Magento 2 - upload SVG files

Tags: magento2, cms

how can I upload SVG files(icons for example) to my cms Page.

If I try to upload them by using "insert image" and upload them to my media storage I always get "Disallowed file type"?

Is there any way to allow the upload of SVG files?

Comment: show what you tried ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that? I tried to upload a .svg file through the magento 2 backend. Content->Page->MyPage->Content Tab->Insert Image..

Comment: keep in mind that svgs are disabled for security reasons. they can contain malicious javascript code.

Comment: Oh, ok I actually did not knew that, thank you! Although I can not really refrain from .svg´s in general.

Comment: I have tried as you said but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Go To File:**  `<your magento dir>/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

Add your extension you want to allow  `<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: how to do the same not changing the core file? is there any way to rewrite it?

Comment: changing Magento core files is REALLY bad practice, especially when you can extend instead. Dmitry's solution is way better.

Comment: It allowed svg , but failed to save and not showing the image preview also

Comment: To those reading: please do not do this. You should never edit Composer files like this

Answer (score 13):

If you wan't change core files add this to di.xml of your module

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

For magento 2.3 a bit different:

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

It isn't clear solution - there will be some errors in admin, but at least it allows you to upload what you want

Comment: The item parameter type changed to string recently with a mime-type value, e.g. <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>

Comment: not working - Magento ver. 2.2.6

Comment: It's no longer working in 2.3 and I suggest whoever wants to use svg to simply give it up. Looks like Magento is determined to phase out svg for security reasons: https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.0.16-and-2.1.9-security-update

Comment: how can working in 2.3? thank you! @EthanWan

Comment: @niceonelee, I've updated the answer

Comment: not working too, showing `File validation failed.` @Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.3, You have to add this to di.xml of your custom module

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free solution that adds the possibility to upload SVG images in Magento: https://github.com/MagestyApps/module-web-images

Answer (score 0):

> **Add Following Two Files**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Framework\File\Uploader"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Framework/File**

**Uploader.php**

```
<?php

    namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Framework\File;

    use Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException;

    class Uploader extends \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader
    {

        protected function _validateFile()
        {
            if ($this->_fileExists === false) {
                return;
            }
            /// You can also add your allow File types in array and check in_array
            if (!$this->getFileExtension() == 'svg') {
                //is file extension allowed
                if (!$this->checkAllowedExtension($this->getFileExtension())) {
                    throw new ValidationException(__('Disallowed file type.'));
                }
            }
            //run validate callbacks
            foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
                if (is_object($params['object'])
                    && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])
                    && is_callable([$params['object'], $params['method']])
                ) {
                    $params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **After adding run below commands**

```
php bin/magento -f module:enable VendoreName_ModuleName --clear-static-content

php bin/magento c:c
```

Now SVG files are allow for upload.