# How can I upload SVG files as Magento product images?

Tags: magento2, product-images, svg

I would like to add SVG files as product images.

How can I accomplish that?

I saw [Magento 2 - upload SVG files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142139/magento-2-upload-svg-files) but it changes core files and is for CMS.

*edit*

it's breaking in `\Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::checkAllowedExtension` -- question is how to influence the list of allowed types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extensions are hard coded in

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Gallery/Upload.php:47
```

Third, you need to use the IMAGEMAGICK adapter.

**FOSS extension** to fix that (self-promotion): https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-module-svg-product-images

Comment: Keep us posted here and on [the GitHub thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2958#issuecomment-313661579) please.

Comment: @benmarks module is on github.

Comment: How do i use this plugin? Is there a composer command or any upload instructions please?

Comment: There is s Composer.json but you might have to add the repo under repositories node. Feel free to improve the readme using a pull request

Comment: I am not a developer nor familiar with Github. Is there any way I can use this extension?

Comment: You can also try to download the zip under releases and put the contents to app/code on a Testserver