# Can I upload SVG images to the products on Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: product, product-images, magento2.2.3, svg

Is it possible to upload SVG images to the products on Magento 2.2.3. I have read many topics related to my issue, but I didn't get a clear solution on that. Please let me know whether it's possible or not.

Is this possible, how to do that?. Please comment[image].

Answer (score 0):

Go To File:  `<your magento dir>/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

Add your extension you want to allow  `<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

If you wan't change core files add this to di.xml of your module

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done as per your suggestion but still I can't upload SVG images. May I know, If the above said update is worked for you?. If yes, please let me explain briefly.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec Any solution?

Comment: try this extension https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-module-svg-product-images
reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182535/how-can-i-upload-svg-files-as-magento-product-images/182617#182617

Comment: I have already tried this extension but not worked for me. Did you try this extension?

Comment: Just to add some content, to why svg upload is disabled by default in magento:
svg pretty much works like a script - so allowing svg upload serverwide, you may also allow customers to upload svg images (contact form, ticket system etc.). Those images are a possible security risk for everyone who opens them. So, be careful with that in mind.