# File type .svg Error in image upload Magento 2.3.1

Tags: image-upload, magento2.3.1, svg

***How to Allowed  file types svg image upload magento 2***

Show in  system.log

```
main.ERROR: Unsupported image format. File:

/var/www/html/pub/media//logos_1.svg
```

Comment: is anything wrong?

Comment: Please refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142139/magento-2-upload-svg-files

Comment: @mighty_hk yes i know  but not working for me

Comment: product images ???

Comment: Did you manage to upload svg? If yes please let me know the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This module makes it possible to upload different filetypes inside the WYSIWYG-editor.*

> *The following filetypes are available by default and it is possible to add extra filetypes to the allowed filetypes in the configuration
>   of the module (General > Content Management > WYSIWYG Options > Extra
>   Allowed Filetypes):*

```
Word (doc, docm, docx)

Excel (csv, xml, xls, xlsx)

PDF (pdf)

Compressed Folder (zip, tar)
```

*https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-WysiwygDownloads*

***You can edit di.xml And add Following code***

```
<item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item> 
</item>

<item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>

<item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>
```

***and in backend set what you need like this***

[image]

Comment: Just adding the code is enough to di.xml or is it required to install the plugin also?

Answer (score 9):

The reason SVG's are disabled in Magento 2 by default, is for security reasons such as stored XSS. And I would recommend that you leave them disabled atleast for now until we get better sanitization for them.

You can see an example of this in `APPSEC-1673`, where they removed SVGs in the favicon

https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2016-and-219-security-update

> `APPSEC-1673` Stored xss using svg images in Favicon.

While you can't upload SVG's via the backend, you can still upload them with FTP and reference them as if you did upload them. This way you still get the benefits of using SVG's but you don't have to deal with the security issues of allowing users to load them.

### Enable SVG upload for Favicon/Logo upload

But if you do still want to enable SVG upload for the favicon/logo upload. You can create a custom module and override xml nodes/php functions where it was removed from. You can find these in the diff below

https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.1.8...2.1.9

### Enable SVG elsewhere

Dependent on where you want to enable SVG uploads will affect what files you will need to override. You should be able to find the files you need to edit by a quick search for `allowedExtensions` in `XML` files or either `getAllowedExtensions` `setAllowedExtensions` in `PHP` files.

Answer (score 6):

open OR overwrite below file and code `<item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>`

```
/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml

<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                ......
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                ......
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                ......
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                ......
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                ......
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                ......
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

If you use below magento 2.3 version , code silde change .
Replace above code `<item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>` To `<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

Comment: still not working File validation failed. and i mention i use magento 2.3.1 version

Answer (score 5):

Open Below File

> `/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

Add your extension you want to allow

> `<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh But still not working

Comment: @SavanPatel you have checked your theme path this file override? if override then this code update in file

Answer (score 1):

**Plugin to Allow SVG Files for Product Images**

[magento2-module-svg-product-images](https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-module-svg-product-images)

Comment: Perfect solution...!!!