# Magento 2: How to enable SVG image for category custom image upload

Tags: magento2, product-images, wysiwyg, svg

I need to enable SVG image in upload for custom module.

I have tried all the solution which i have found.

Here is my code:

> /etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                </item>
                <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">text/html</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Any idea? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please Follow this link might be helpful [image category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129870/magento-2-create-category-attribute-thumbnail-and-upload-image-using-file-upload)

Comment: Did you try this one => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277417/file-type-svg-error-in-image-upload-magento-2-3-1

Comment: @Shiwani check it Ref:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279045/68695

Comment: checked..Not working

Comment: Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a free solution that allows uploading SVG image all over Magento 2: https://github.com/MagestyApps/module-web-images

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2.3 version
in etc directory in your module create di.xml file with code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="RemoveSvgFromNotProtectedExtension" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension"/>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">svg</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="allowedMimeTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

and create plugin file Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension.php with code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\File\Validator;

class NotProtectedExtension
{


/**
 * Remove svg from Not Protected Extensions
 * 
 * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension $extension
 * @param array $result
 * @return array
 */
public function afterGetProtectedFileExtensions(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension $extension,
    $result
) {
    if (in_array('svg', $result)) {
        unset($result['svg']);
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

thats all)