# Magento 2.3.2 - SVG Logo not supported

Tags: image-upload, magento2.3.2, svg

I have tried to upload SVG logo in Magento 2.3.2 but its shows error "We don't recognize or support this file extension type"

Comment: Magento 2 only JPG, GIF, PNG format support for Logo image but you can give direct media file path for SVG logo.

Comment: There is no way to upload svg logo from backend? I have found the solution, but not working in magento 2.3.X - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142139/magento-2-upload-svg-files