# How can i upload SVG image on Magento 2.3.6?

Tags: magento2.3, image-upload, file-upload, di.xml, svg

Please help me.

Now i can't upload SVG image on Magento V-2.3.6. I tried with below code but still can't.

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">

<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
<item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>
<item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
    <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
</item>
<item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
    <item name="swf" xsi:type="string">application/x-shockwave-flash</item>
    <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
    <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
    <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
    <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142150/72911)

**Go To File:**  `<your magento dir>/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`

Add your extension you want to allow  `<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: can't. show "File validation failed."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free extension that does the trick: https://github.com/MagestyApps/module-web-images